# Confused with proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I would like to use proguard to obfuscate my code, but am getting confused about the doc. It says that I need to set the proguard.config property in project.properties, but this file contains:
**Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!**
Should I just ignore this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only non documented changes will be erased. You can add your proguard path without having to worry about getting your changes erased.